# Always operate at Time.timeScale = 1?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, time

How do I make a specific script always operate at `Time.timeScale = 1` **no matter what**? I want it to override even when another script calls `Time.timeScale = 0` for example.

Comment: You would probably better to implement your own mechanism then

Comment: never, ever change timeScale for any reason.

Comment: @JoeBlow Not even for pausing? Is there an alternative way to pause?

Comment: Pausing in video games is very difficult.  You must actual write pauses for all your heros, NPCs, enemies, backgrounds, effects, everything. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start your own coroutine, with `StartCoroutine()` in your coroutine you can use `yield return new WaitForSeconds(sec)` where `sec` is equal to whatever your timestep is. See [Edit > Project Settings > Time](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TimeManager.html)

Comment: I don't really understand your answer. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Let's say that `Update()` is called around every `0.02` seconds. Unity does that automatically. But you could also create your own method that is called every `0.02` seconds. You should look into coroutines. And look into `WaitForSeconds`.

Comment: I also do not see how this relates to the question.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is when you write a coroutine, you yourself have control over the timing. Beware that `WaitForSeconds` is still affected by `Time.timeScale` so you'll have to divide the amount of seconds by `Time.timeScale`.